# Aguilera-Perez Algorithm of $nD$ rotation matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm, rotation

I want to compute a general $nD$ [rotation matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) which corresponds to a rotation by an angle $\theta$ around an $(n−2)$-dimensional subspace.

I found the Aguilera-Perez algorithm in their [paper](http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2004/Papers_2004_Short/N29.pdf):

[image: algorithm]

where the $R_{a,b}(\theta)$ matrix is defined as follows
[image: notation]

How do you find a $2D$ rotation matrix (and in general an $nD$ rotation matrix) according to the Aguilera-Perez Algorithm using *Mathematica*?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need this. Did you know `RotationMatrix[]` can take an angle and two vectors spanning a plane as arguments?

Comment: @J.M.   there is a [Rodrigues' Rotation Formula](http://i.imgur.com/nogL1ix.png) for $3D$ rotation matrix corresponding to a rotation by an angle $\theta$ about a fixed axis specified by the unit vector $\hat{\omega}=(\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z) \in R^3$. How to get this formula from   `RotationMatrix[]`?

Comment: If you've tried to implement the algorithm, please post your code and point out what *Mathematica*-related difficulties you're having. The second line contains undefined quantities.

Comment: From a quick read of the paper… it looks to me that they just reimplemented QR (actually, LQ due to their chosen order of operations) decomposition with Givens (or in this context, rotation) matrices.

Comment: The n-dimensional rotation can be described with the Exponatilamatrix `Exp[Phi] `(Eulerrotation=natural rotation), `Phi==-Phi^t ` is a skew Matrix. Knowing the scalar  identity   `Exp[x] == (1 + Tanh[x/2])/(1 - Tanh[x/2])` one can conclude for the rotation matrix  `Exp[Phi] ==(1 - Tanh[Phi/2])^-1 (1+Tanh[Phi/2])`. The mapping `Tanh[Phi/2]` is the Rodrigues Rotation!